# What is the benefit of using inline css vs external css file for background image

Tags: html, css, inline

I'm kind of deciding which will be the best approach here. Let say I have a background image that I want to attached to multiple pages (each page with different background image). The page itself will be responsive. Will it be better if I do something like this (inline css):-

```
<div class="hero" style="background: url('../images/pagebg.jpg') no-repeat 50% 50% / cover;"></div>
```

or I have an external css and do something like this:-

```
.hero {  
height: 100%;
width: 100%;   
position: relative;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
display: block;    
}
.hero-page1bg {
background: url('../images/pg1.jpg') no-repeat 50% 50% ;
background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
}
```

and in my html page I put this

```
<div class="hero .hero-page1bg"></div>
```

I'm more leaning to the second approach because it gives me the flexibility of using media queries and assign a smaller file size for different devices comparing to the first approach (inline css). But I've seen so many responsive website using the first approach (inline css) and calling the same background file for all devices (based on folder structure and file name), thus forcing those mobile devices to download big file size.

If you have to manage a site via CMS the inline css looks like a logical approach as it seems to be easier to do inline css than getting the client to change the CSS file.

What is the right approach guys? Inline or external? And with and without CMS? Which way will you go?

Thank you in advance. Cheers

Comment: Reduces file size and creates cleaner html documents.  It is very convenient that you don't have to write the same style across every page.  If you change it in the external css file all the html docs will change too.

Comment: Thanks Rafael, I do understand the benefit of inline vs external. I'm just trying to understand why so many digital agency company website are using inline css for their responsive website. Is there are reason why and I'm missing it?

Comment: Let me give you the best tip in the world.  Don't compare yourself to anybodies work.  You are setting limitations for yourself.  If you know the benefits already...know it in your heart and program the way you do.  That is what will make you better than the rest.  Understand this, there are a whole lot of terrible programers out there....even if they work for a "design company". Take the best and leave the rest...

Comment: You know something Rafael, I kind of agree with you on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use the second approach. Always avoid using inline css, it is really a bad practice even if you are using a CMS.

You should keep your HTML's clean (the same approach also apply to javascript). At first it will seem helpful and util but later when you need to maintain your code it could be a mess.

Comment: My thought too, I rarely or maybe never really use inline css (unless I'm coding email html). I will always do my css externally. It is definitely easier than having to search the pages when you want to make changes. But why so many digital agency company website are using inline css for their background images? I just want to know if I'm missing something here. ie some BIG benefits that I didn't know or read about.

I know some of them are using some JS to write the code to the HTML dynamically but for some, its just obvious that it is a plain inline css.

Answer (score 0):

The typical reason to split into separate style sheet is due to more of a code/ui separation thing, although this will inevitably lead to opinion-based answers on "what is code" and "what is ui" (/styling).

However you've basically answered the question for yourself: media queries are a big bonus when going for fluid layouts. 
You can also cache the heck out of a css file, reducing overall server load.

Comment: That is my thought, but I've seen so many responsive website (we can go to sites like http://www.awwwards.com/websites/responsive-design/ and just look at the most of the sites there, they seems to be using inline css for their background. Just keep me wondering why do they do that? How are they helping those mobile users? 

Is it got anything to do with managing the site with CMS? That is the only logical way I can see myself using inline css as it is easier to get clients to change inline css comparing to external css.